# Angular ng new Test result error in "npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED"

Tags: angular, npm

i was trying to install angular after updating from angular 12.
Command i used:

```
ng version
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm cache clean
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng version
```

Creating a new angular app result error in "npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED"
My option in creating is not create an angular routing and use SCSS.
Error report :

```
- Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! AC0A0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC-Bengkel\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-12T04_09_27_982Z-debug-0.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

This is my current node js and angular cli:

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.5
Node: 18.15.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1502.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         15.2.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   15.2.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          15.2.5 (cli-only)
```

I have deleted the created angular folder and tried again but it got same error.
I havent done anything since i cant find my problem.

Comment: Angular 15 doesn't support Node version `18.15.x`, only `18.10.x` if you want to use node 18.

Comment: With Node: 18.10.0 it still gives this error: / Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! AC210000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:312:
npm ERR!